# How to I make my python script stand alone that has webdriver dependency?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

So I have written a script in python that used selenium to automate some websites. I want this script to be able to be run on a windows computer as an exe maybe?

My question is, how do I approach this?  My script has a dependency on geckodriver.exe

How do I embed that into the final executable file?

Answer (score 0):

There is an automated way to get `gecko driver` binary download etc with `webdrivermanager` api. This package downloads binaries/executables in an automated way and helps us to avoid all the manual steps that we do previously related to drivers to run our tests.

**How do we use this in our project?**

Only setup required is to install this package using ‘pip’.

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

**For Firefox**

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
print driver.title
driver.quit()
```

You can check more details [here](http://allselenium.info/browser-drivers-with-python-webdrivermanager/)  about set up and use. Pypi docs for [webdrivermanager](https://pypi.org/project/webdrivermanager/)